# Bounds of Integration for Nonhomogenous Linear System of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the method of variation of parameters for a system of linear differential equations, I'm just confused about the integration part. When you integrate from t0 to t, does it matter what t0 you choose as long as it is in the domain? Or are you supposed to choose 0? Because the integral yields different +C answers in both components of the matrix depending on your choice of t0.

Comment: Hello! [This link](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx) with a related site may help. Also, please try to write in separate paragraphs, take a [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), read the [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), and [Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)! The first link is a Paul’s Notes link. Also, the constants in the differential equation seem to already have the constant of integration information answered.

Comment: The integration constants will only give contributions corresponding to solutions of the homogeneous systems (that are already known from the outset anyway), so the difference doesn't matter.